# how to use d3-tip to add tooltip to moving objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I am trying to add tool-tip([using this page](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579)) to the source code was given in this [link](http://www.tnoda.com/blog/2014-04-02).
I add the the d3.tip.v0.6.3.js link in html file. Then, I defined the tool tip function inside the flightanimation.js as follows:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
           .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
           .offset([-10, 0])
           .html(function(d) {return "<span> hi </span>"});
svg.call(tip);
```

I added the style of corresponding class in html file as follows:

```
d3-tip {
        line-height: 1;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 12px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
       }
```

I also added

```
 .on('mouseover', tip.show)
 .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
```

to the end of plane in flightanimation.js as follows:

```
var plane = svg.append("path")
               .attr("class", "plane")
               .attr("d", "m25.21488,3.93375c-0.44355,0 -0.84275,0.18332 -1.17933,0.51592c-0.33397,0.33267 -0.61055,0.80884 -0.84275,1.40377c-0.45922,1.18911 -0.74362,2.85964 -0.89755,4.86085c-0.15655,1.99729 -0.18263,4.32223 -0.11741,6.81118c-5.51835,2.26427 -16.7116,6.93857 -17.60916,7.98223c-1.19759,1.38937 -0.81143,2.98095 -0.32874,4.03902l18.39971,-3.74549c0.38616,4.88048 0.94192,9.7138 1.42461,13.50099c-1.80032,0.52703 -5.1609,1.56679 -5.85232,2.21255c-0.95496,0.88711 -0.95496,3.75718 -0.95496,3.75718l7.53,-0.61316c0.17743,1.23545 0.28701,1.95767 0.28701,1.95767l0.01304,0.06557l0.06002,0l0.13829,0l0.0574,0l0.01043,-0.06557c0,0 0.11218,-0.72222 0.28961,-1.95767l7.53164,0.61316c0,0 0,-2.87006 -0.95496,-3.75718c-0.69044,-0.64577 -4.05363,-1.68813 -5.85133,-2.21516c0.48009,-3.77545 1.03061,-8.58921 1.42198,-13.45404l18.18207,3.70115c0.48009,-1.05806 0.86881,-2.64965 -0.32617,-4.03902c-0.88969,-1.03062 -11.81147,-5.60054 -17.39409,-7.89352c0.06524,-2.52287 0.04175,-4.88024 -0.1148,-6.89989l0,-0.00476c-0.15655,-1.99844 -0.44094,-3.6683 -0.90277,-4.8561c-0.22699,-0.59493 -0.50356,-1.07111 -0.83754,-1.40377c-0.33658,-0.3326 -0.73578,-0.51592 -1.18194,-0.51592l0,0l-0.00001,0l0,0z")
               .on('mouseover', tip.show)
               .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
```

When I ran it, and moved the cursor on the plane object it did not show anything.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?
Any suggestions or advices will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.